# header sent by curl does not contain POST data

Tags: php, curl

The function:

```
function post_with_curl($target,$ref, $name ,$viewStateValue )
    {
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $target) ;       // Target site

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, str_replace('\\','/', getcwd().'/'."cook.txt" )); //CHANGE THIS 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $ref);  
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, CURL_TIMEOUT);    // Timeout
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, WEBBOT_NAME); 
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);


        $postfields = urlencode('__EVENTTARGET=&__EVENTARGUMENT=&__VIEWSTATE=.'. $viewStateValue. '&__VIEWSTATEENCRYPTED=&ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$NameSearch1$CompanyNameTextBox1='.$name.'&ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$SearchButton=Search Now' ) ;
        curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postfields );

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);     // Follow redirects
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 4);             // Limit redirections to four
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);     // Return in string  
        $curled_page = curl_exec($ch);
        var_dump(curl_getinfo($ch , CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT)) ;
        curl_close($ch);
        return $curled_page ;
    }
```

The result of  var_dump(curl_getinfo($ch , CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT)) :

```
string 'POST /V2/COUNTY/Default.aspx HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:5.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/5.0
Host: 198.173.15.31
Accept: */*
Referer: http://198.173.15.31/V2/COUNTY/
Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=pqfpur45akgy3l45ujq3fail
Content-Length: 1603
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Expect: 100-continue

' (length=339)
```

As I see it, the header(being sent by curl?) does not contain any POST data. Why ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because post data is not part of the headers of a HTTP message, but part of the HTTP message body. If you get the headers, you don't get the body. If you want to retrieve the body you must retrieve the message body.

BTW you don't need to retrieve it because you already created it on your own into the `$postfields` variable. That's merely the data being posted.

Or did I misread what you're actually asking for?

Comment: ok so how do I see the HTTP message body being sent by curl? i just want to see the exact data being exchanged between curl and the server and then compare it with the data being exchanged between the server and firefox.

Comment: As far as I know, the PHP curl version does not offer such a functionality. I even scanned the manual quickly for that. I assume that it will get passed exactly like in the string you create, but I do not 100% know. But I think it's very, very likely. As an alternative you can sniff the network traffic and watch the request in there. This will give you 100% satisfaction and will work with every HTTP client.

Comment: Probably curl can log each request. It might be in the log then as well.